# Add a class to element with matching data attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I want to add a class to an element that shares the same data attribute value using vanilla JS. The class is added on `mouseenter`.

My current setup only applies the class on hover to the first element and ignores the rest.

```js
let section = document.querySelector('.section');
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.links a');
let triggerVal;
let linkedVal;

links.forEach(function(link, index) {
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    triggerVal = this.dataset.triggerValue;
    linkedVal = section.dataset.linkedValue;

    if (linkedVal === triggerVal) {
      section.classList.add('is-active');
    } else {
      section.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li>
    <a data-trigger-value="red" href="#">Red</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-trigger-value="yellow" href="#">Yellow</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-trigger-value="blue" href="#">Blue</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section" data-linked-value="red">
    <h2>Red</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-linked-value="yellow">
    <h2>Yellow</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-linked-value="blue">
    <h2>Blue</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/7378e190ed6ad117faca968b634520b0

I've got a feeling it's to do with the `.section` element but I've tried a few things and nothing seems to give me what I need.

Any suggestions as to what I need to do to get the rest of the elements working?

Comment: `let section = document.querySelector('.section');` will only return the first matching element.

Comment: Yeah that's where I'm going wrong - what's needed to target all of them?

Comment: querySelectorAll, then in your forEach for the links you also need to loop the sections and compare the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change two things:

First, get **all** sections:

```
const section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
```

Then, inside your handler, you need to iterate over the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll()`:

```
    for (const section of sections) {
        linkedVal = section.dataset.linkedValue;

        if (linkedVal === triggerVal) {
            section.classList.add('is-active');
        } else {
            section.classList.remove('is-active');
        }   
    }
```

This is your new JS:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.links a');
let triggerVal;
let linkedVal;

links.forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        triggerVal = e.target.dataset.triggerValue;
        for (const section of sections) {
            linkedVal = section.dataset.linkedValue;

            if (linkedVal === triggerVal) {
                section.classList.add('is-active');
            } else {
                section.classList.remove('is-active');
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: was working on a similar answer but @connexo beat me to it. this is the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` for `sections` and then `forEach`. And use `toggle` instead of `add/remove` for this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.links a');
let triggerVal;
let linkedVal;

links.forEach(function(link, index) {
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    triggerVal = this.dataset.triggerValue;
    sections.forEach(
        section => section.classList.toggle(
            'is-active',
            section.dataset.linkedValue === triggerValue
        )
    );
  });
});
```